# ERROR Deploying a Java web application with Visual Studio Code and Tomcat for Java extension

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I'm deploying a Deploying a Java web application with Visual Studio Code and Tomcat for Java extension.

I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException librerias\jquery-ui-1.8.2\development-bundle\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png.
```

I deploy the same web application outside Visual studio Code, in the webapp folder of my Tomcat and the web application runs without any problems.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: have you install the extension correctly ？you could refer to [Tomcat](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tomcat-jetty#_tomcat) and [web app](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-webapp)

Comment: I delete the folder \jquery-ui-1.8.2 from my source code, and then I can deploy the war with the Tomcat extesion from Visual Studio Code.Obviously, I need the jquery-ui-1.8.2 library in my project an I cand deltete.....

I think the Tomcat extesion can't deploy a path so large............Any suggestion???